# XSLT 1.0 specific output, if condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

can you help me please?

If there are differents at "PackingslipId"-"LineItem"-"Lines" i don´t like to have "PackingslipId" and "DeliveryDate" on "HeaderInformation".

If the "PackingslipId" is always the same at "LineItem"-"Lines" than on "HeaderInformation" the output "PackingslipId" and "DeliveryDate" is ok.

Please note: (I don´t no if important; it also can be, that there is just one Article ("LineItem"-"Lines" - with "OrderLineNum" 1) - in this case, the "PackingslipId" is the same of "Lines" and "HeaderInformation" so "PackingslipId" and "DeliveryDate" should be also on "HeaderInformation" and "LineItem"

My XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
 <Interchange>
  <Recipient></Recipient>
  <Sender></Sender>
  <CreationDate>2018-11-19:07:06:20</CreationDate>
  <Test>No</Test>
  <Interchange_Control_Number></Interchange_Control_Number>
  <HeaderInformation>
   <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
   <InvoiceType>INVOIC</InvoiceType>
   <InvoiceDate>2018-11-19</InvoiceDate>
   <InvoiceNumber>FV1800087</InvoiceNumber>
   <CustomerOrderReference></CustomerOrderReference>
   <SalesOrderReference></SalesOrderReference>
   <SalesOrderDate>2018-11-15T07:22:01</SalesOrderDate>
   <PackingslipId>AV1800097</PackingslipId>
   <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
   <Currency>EUR</Currency>
   <TaxExempt></TaxExempt>
   <Contact />
   <TermsOfPayment>
    <PaymTermDescription></PaymTermDescription>
    <DueDate></DueDate>
   </TermsOfPayment>
   <CashDiscountConditions />
   <WeightAndVolume>
    <NetWeight></NetWeight>
    <UnifOfWeight></UnifOfWeight>
   </WeightAndVolume>
   <SupplierAddressInformation>
    <GLN></GLN>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street></Street>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <City></City>
    <Country></Country>
    <CoRegNum></CoRegNum>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
   </SupplierAddressInformation>
   <BuyerAddressInformation>
    <Name></Name>
    <Country></Country>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
    <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
   </BuyerAddressInformation>
   <InvoiceAddressInformation>
    <GLN></GLN>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street></Street>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <City></City>
    <Country></Country>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
    <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
   </InvoiceAddressInformation>
   <DeliveryAddressInformation>
    <GLN></GLN>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street></Street>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <City></City>
    <Country></Country>
    <State></State>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
    <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
   </DeliveryAddressInformation>
   <TransportDetails>
    <DeliveryTerms></DeliveryTerms>
   </TransportDetails>
   <LineItem>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>1</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800097</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>2</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800098</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>3</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800099</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>4</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800099</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
   </LineItem>
   <Totals>
    <InvoiceTotal></InvoiceTotal>
    <NetAmount></NetAmount>
    <VATAmount></VATAmount>
    <DiscountAmount></DiscountAmount>
    <AllowanceOrChargeAmount></AllowanceOrChargeAmount>
    <DueDate></DueDate>
    <VAT>
     <VATS>
      <Percentage></Percentage>
      <Type></Type>
      <BaseAmount></BaseAmount>
      <VATAmount></VATAmount>
     </VATS>
    </VAT>
   </Totals>
  </HeaderInformation>
 </Interchange>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

My XSLT:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:key name="header_text" match="HeaderText" use="Text"/>
  <xsl:key name="line_text" match="LineText" use="concat(../OrderLineNum, '|', Text)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- no duplilcate on HeaderText and LineText -->
  <xsl:template match="HeaderText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('header_text', Text)[1])]" />
  <xsl:template match="LineText[generate-id() != generate-id(key('line_text', concat(../OrderLineNum, '|', Text))[1])]" />
  
  <!-- delete PackingslipId on HeaderInformation, if different at Line -->
  <xsl:template match="/salesinvoices/lineItem">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="
      count(lines[not(PackingslipId = preceding-sibling::lines/PackingslipId)]) = 1">

        <xsl:copy-of select="//HeaderInformation/PackingslipId"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//HeaderInformation/DeliveryDate"/>
   
        </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>            
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- delete empty nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct Output should be: (no PackingslipId and no DeliveryDate on HeaderInformation, because there are differents at LineItem - PackingslipId)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
 <Interchange>
  <Recipient></Recipient>
  <Sender></Sender>
  <CreationDate>2018-11-19:07:06:20</CreationDate>
  <Test>No</Test>
  <Interchange_Control_Number></Interchange_Control_Number>
  <HeaderInformation>
   <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
   <InvoiceType>INVOIC</InvoiceType>
   <InvoiceDate>2018-11-19</InvoiceDate>
   <InvoiceNumber>FV1800087</InvoiceNumber>
   <CustomerOrderReference></CustomerOrderReference>
   <SalesOrderReference></SalesOrderReference>
   <SalesOrderDate>2018-11-15T07:22:01</SalesOrderDate>   
   <Currency>EUR</Currency>
   <TaxExempt></TaxExempt>
   <Contact />
   <TermsOfPayment>
    <PaymTermDescription></PaymTermDescription>
    <DueDate></DueDate>
   </TermsOfPayment>
   <CashDiscountConditions />
   <WeightAndVolume>
    <NetWeight></NetWeight>
    <UnifOfWeight></UnifOfWeight>
   </WeightAndVolume>
   <SupplierAddressInformation>
    <GLN></GLN>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street></Street>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <City></City>
    <Country></Country>
    <CoRegNum></CoRegNum>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
   </SupplierAddressInformation>
   <BuyerAddressInformation>
    <Name></Name>
    <Country></Country>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
    <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
   </BuyerAddressInformation>
   <InvoiceAddressInformation>
    <GLN></GLN>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street></Street>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <City></City>
    <Country></Country>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
    <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
   </InvoiceAddressInformation>
   <DeliveryAddressInformation>
    <GLN></GLN>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street></Street>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <City></City>
    <Country></Country>
    <State></State>
    <VATNum></VATNum>
    <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
   </DeliveryAddressInformation>
   <TransportDetails>
    <DeliveryTerms></DeliveryTerms>
   </TransportDetails>
   <LineItem>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>1</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800097</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>2</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800098</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>3</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800099</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
     <OrderLineNum>4</OrderLineNum>
     <PackingslipId>AV1800099</PackingslipId>
     <DeliveryDate>2018-11-19</DeliveryDate>
     <GTIN></GTIN>
     <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
     <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
     <Quantity></Quantity>
     <PriceUnit></PriceUnit>
     <FixedPrice></FixedPrice>
     <SalesPrice></SalesPrice>
     <DiscAmount></DiscAmount>
     <DiscPercent></DiscPercent>
     <SalesLinePercent1></SalesLinePercent1>
     <SalesLinePercent2></SalesLinePercent2>
     <MultiLnDisc></MultiLnDisc>
     <MultiLnPercent></MultiLnPercent>
     <LineAmount></LineAmount>
     <SumLineDisc></SumLineDisc>
     <DeliveredQuantity></DeliveredQuantity>
     <VatBaseAmount></VatBaseAmount>
     <VatPercentage></VatPercentage>
     <Measure_Unit></Measure_Unit>
    </Lines>
   </LineItem>
   <Totals>
    <InvoiceTotal></InvoiceTotal>
    <NetAmount></NetAmount>
    <VATAmount></VATAmount>
    <DiscountAmount></DiscountAmount>
    <AllowanceOrChargeAmount></AllowanceOrChargeAmount>
    <DueDate></DueDate>
    <VAT>
     <VATS>
      <Percentage></Percentage>
      <Type></Type>
      <BaseAmount></BaseAmount>
      <VATAmount></VATAmount>
     </VATS>
    </VAT>
   </Totals>
  </HeaderInformation>
 </Interchange>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

Thanks a lot,

best regards
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add these two templates to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[PackingslipId != LineItem/Lines/PackingslipId]/PackingslipId" />
<xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[PackingslipId != LineItem/Lines/PackingslipId]/DeliveryDate" />
```

Or, if you want to combine these two into one, just add this template

```
<xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[PackingslipId != LineItem/Lines/PackingslipId]/*[self::PackingslipId or self::DeliveryDate]" />
```